# VHF Artifact Contaminating Electrophysiological Sleep Signals

Tags: noise, eeg

I am trying to remove an artifact from a VHF transmitter (programmed at a frequency of 148535; 1.5sec between 200ms pulses; 1.7sec peak to peak) from a sleep recording (polysomnography recording with electroencephalogram, electromyogram, electrooculogram, and electrocardiogram sampled at 500Hz) of a wild animal. There is a large electrical artifact picked up independently by each of 9 electrophysiological channels generated by the VHF transmitter (a consequence of moving from the lab to the field, because we use these to locate our animals in the field). The biggest problem with the VHF signal is that it changes amplitude based on where the animal is (goes away - signal is attenuated - when the animal is underwater and the artifact reverses polarity from time to time when the animal moves).

I tried band-pass filtering the signals, to try to eliminate higher frequency signals (for example from 0.3 to 35 Hz for EEG and electrooculogram (EOG) and 0.3 to 75 Hz for electrocardiogram (ECG) and 10 to 100 Hz for electromyogram (EMG), and the signal is still there, just gets a bit warped depending on filter settings.

I've also run an independent components analysis in EEGLAB (increasingly standardized for EEG analysis) to see if it can recognize the VHF signal and extract it. If I train the algorithm on the entire dataset, it comes up with a decomposition that doesn't separate out the VHF signal. If I train the algorithm on just a section of the data, it fits that section well, but these ICA weights don't extrapolate well to the rest of the data. In some places, they are able to remove the artifact, but in others, they add it back in.

Please let me know if you have any ideas for what I could try. I am a biologist and do not have a ton of machine learning or programming expertise, but am coding in MATLAB where I have been running the EEGLAB toolbox.

Here is an example of the intermittent signal changing polarity and amplitude over time.
[image: Here is an example of the intermittent signal changing polarity and amplitude over time.]

Comment: Could you let us know, what is the artifact that's troubling?, is it some high amplitude nosie at a particular frequency. I am not familiar with the nature of an EEG signal, so it is not obvious from the plot.

Comment: A VHF pulse transmitter at 148.535 MHz with 200 ms pulses spaced 1.7 sec apart sounds like an animal tracking tag.  Those things certainly won't be frequency stable down to  +/- 250 Hz of frequency error, so when your device samples your signals of interest using a 500 Hz sample rate, the VHF signal could fold in anywhere in your 500 Hz bandwidth. Your best bet is inline analog lowpass filters on the inputs of your device that receives the input signals and converts them to digital sample streams.  The device also needs metal foil shielding tied to ground to block VHF and other EMI.

Comment: Also consider that the VHF pulse signal could be so strong, that it is overdriving the likely very high gain, sensitive inputs in your device, causing clipping and generating intermodulation products (non-AWGN noise) internally.  This makes the VHF interfering signal spectrum in your baseband not that of just a single pulsed tone, so ti would be close to impossible to adaptively detect, track, and filter out using standard signal processing techniques.  Improving desired signal to non-deterministic non-AWGN noise ratio is a hard task.  It's better to keep the VHF out in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Andy- yes exactly, an animal tracking tag! We'll definitely want to keep it out in the future.. We may have to forfeit the ability to track the animal using VHF and instead opt for a GPS transmitter or just visual scanning. We have a more heavily EMI-shielded version for lab use, but were not anticipating electrical noise in the wild environment.

As for the existing data, do you have any additional ideas for analysis? I think I will run independent components analysis on small portions of the data (~10min), in which the VHF signal is fairly consistent to remove the VHF component.

Comment: I have some ideas for analysis, but before I write up something, can you answer these 2 Qs: 1) Are your sample streams complex (with In-phase and Quadrature data) or just real sample streams (just In-phase)?  2) Do you plan on processing a data stream all at once in MatLab, or is it so large that you must chunk it up and processes in a streaming fashion?    In any case, realize that not all the data will be salvagable: when the EMI overdrives your input amplifiers so that they clip the input, information from your signal of interest is lost during the clip.

Comment: Hi Andy: I believe that my sample streams are just real numbers (no complex numbers), but am not 100% sure as that is a bit beyond my conceptual understanding. As for processing- the whole recording is 3.5 days and I was thinking that I would have to chunk it into smaller sections because the VHF artifact is not consistent across the recording, as it changes in amplitude as the animal goes in and out of the water. Luckily, there are only a few sections where the signal is actually clipped, but there are many sections which have significant warping. I'd appreciate any feedback you have.